# SPfx SuiteNavBranding for text and url

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, navigation, 2019, global-navigation

I am looking for some guidance in regards to changing SuiteNavBranding using SPfx (which I am new to).

I need to change the link and the text.

Sitting on SP2019 on premise. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: SPfx is quite complex unless you have rich JS & Node.js experience.  It is not easy task. I suggest you take a look on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment.

Comment: There is easier way to change the text. Take a look on : https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/10/customize-suitebar-text-link-in-sharepoint-2016-using-powershell.html